# mvc 3 conditional Remote Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Here's my model:

```
public class StockRequestModel
  {
    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string TranCode { get; set; }

    [Remote("CheckAvailableStocks", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "ItemID")]
    public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }

    public decimal ItemValue { get; set; }
    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    public int MaterialRequesitionID { get; set; }
    public int ReturnedByID { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
  }
```

This model was used by multiple pages on my site. Please help me on how to enable/disable this remote on certain pages only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create seperate viewmodels for each view and **Inherit** it from the class which is common for all

```
public class StockRequestBase
{
   public int StockID { get; set; }
   public int CategoryID { get; set; }
   public int ItemID { get; set; }
   public string TranCode { get; set; }
   //other common properties
}
public class AddStockRequest : StockRequestBase
{
   [Remote("CheckAvailableStocks", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "ItemID")]
   public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
}
public class AddStockRequestOptional : StockRequestBase
{
    public int ItemQuantity { get; set; }
    public string AnotherSpecificAttribute { set;get;}
}
```